# creating new dataframe from other dataframes' but index and values(Nan) problem keep occurs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new dataframe using other dataframes', but the new dataframe keep sets the column row as index, and other row's values are missing.

but the output had 2 problems.
column 'a' was set to index.
and column 'c' had no values in.

how can i make it right??

my input:

```py
cc = pd.DataFrame({
    'a' : [1,2,3],
    'b' : [2,3,4]
})

dd = pd.DataFrame({
    'c' : [3,4,5],
    'd' : [4,5,6]
})

ee = pd.DataFrame(cc['a'], dd['c'])
print(ee)
```

my output:

```
    a
c   
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
```

desired :

```
a   c
1   3
2   4
3   5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers! But i forgot write that actually i want to know why it doesn't work. Cause I could see it works if there's only one row (pd.DataFrame(cc['a'])).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.concat`:

```py
ee = pd.concat([cc["a"], dd["c"]], axis=1)
print(ee)
```

Prints:

```
   a  c
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dict`
Column name as key, series as value.

```
ee = pd.DataFrame({"a":cc['a'], "c": dd['c']})
```